# How to select a dropdown option based on the given ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown (ie html select+options).

If I reload the page with a route "#/make/ROLLS ROYCE/", how do I get the dropdown to preselect the option "ROLLS ROYCE"?

```
var makes = ["ABARTH", "ALFA ROMEO", "ASTON MARTIN", "ROLLS ROYCE"]
var homeApp = angular.module('homeApp', ['ngRoute']);

homeApp.config(function ($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Make/:make', {controller: MakeModelCtrl, template:''})
    $routeProvider.otherwise({controller: MakeModelCtrl, template:''})
});

function MakeModelCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log($scope, $location, $routeParams)
}
```

and

```
<form data-ng-controller="MakeModelCtrl">
<div>
    <select data-ng-model="make" data-ng-options="make for make in makes">
        <option value="">Make</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
<div data-ng-view></div>
```

Using the route, this much will populate the dropdown, and the console will show a routeParam of "{make: "ROLLS ROYCE"}".  The option values are 0..n with the various names.

How do I get the dropdown option to match the url param?
Should I be using ngRoute? or location? 
Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to watch for route change success events `routeChangeSuccess` MakeModelCtrl

In that you can set your make based on routeparams

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
       $scope.make=$routeParams.make;
});
```